How to do copy of all the containers without explicitly mentioning in the array between two different storage accounts
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78351368/22054564
In my previous question-solution, i asked to change the names of the containers in the target storage account but now I do not want to change.
I have created

Linked Services for source and target storage accounts.
Integration Runtime created in Virtual Network as the storage accounts are in virtual network.

I don't know what are the next steps to copy all the containers as-is from source to destination.
could anyone help me on this!

To achieve your desired requirement, you can follow below procedure:
Create binary dataset with source linked services by leaving file path as empty as shown below:

Add Get meta data activity to the pipeline, select above data set for it with Child items as Field list shown below:

You will get list of all containers in the storage account as output of meta data activity as shown below:

Add for each activity on success of get meta data activity with @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems items.
Create source and sink binary data sets with dataset parameter container_name for container name in file path as shown below:

Inside foreach add copy activity configure both source and sink with created datasets as shown below:
Source:

Sink:

Debug the pipeline, copy all the containers as-is from source storage account to destination storage account as shown below:


Hi @Bhavani, Will this copy containers as well as the folders and files inside the containers?

Yes it copies all containers as well as with sub folders and files inside it.

Also, In the Get MetaData activity - what is the value of the parameter container_name? Reference - https://i.imgur.com/HNdE69p.png

What is the container_name value in the linked service parameter?

HI @Bhavani, Do i have to provide container names separated by commas  or what is the value of container_name given in the Linked Services Parameter? Could you please solve this doubt asap.

I have taken value from get meta data activity for dataset parameter container_name

In get meta data create new dataset with file path empty as mentioned in my solution don't use same datasets in source in copy activity and meta data activity
